# How to decide which collection will best suited for your requirement

Tags: c#, .net

Recently in an interview, I was asked a question -

Let's we have billion of data in a file system [Assuming data is already being fetched by existing code] what my task was to find the Person name using the email id as search criteria with best case complexity.
Also, what collection is best suited for this?

```
public class Person
 {
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public string Email {get;set;}
 }
```

Comment: Have you thought about using a `Dictionary<string, string>`? Where the `key` is `Email` and the `Name` is the value. You can just then use a simple check to see if that dictionary contains the email address as a key - `if (dict.ContainsKey("email@domain.com")) { var match = dict["email@domain.com"].Value; }`

Comment: This sounds like a bit of a trick question. There are two giveaways. 1) they specified that the data is in a file system. 2) there are billions of them. They're deliberately describing something that you can't directly query in real time. It would take forever to find a record, longer if multiple users tried to execute simultaneous queries. The answer isn't to query the files - it's to convert the data to something that you can query.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with email as the key
It is O(1) lookup by key
And email would hash very nicely

For value you can use Name or Person

There is also [KeyedCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx) that is O(1) but that would almost be showing off.

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary<string,string>` would be my answer.

Arguing about the overhead of the class is irelevant. Under the hood, keys are implemented as a hash table. Retrieval by key is approaching O(1) complexity.

In your case the unique key would be the email address and person's name would be value.

Comment: I think we have a voter that does not like Dictionary.

Comment: @Paparazzi It might be a simple coincidence. Scott is not that wrong neither, It's correct to point out there's no way to query that in real time. btw, if it makes your day better, there you go. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can't (or really, really shouldn't) plan on searching billions of files to find one with a matching email address. That's like reading every book in the library to find out which ones were written by certain author. What you need (just as they have at the library) is an index. You might have to do all of the work to read and parse all of that content once to build the index, but then when you need a particular file or files you search the index, not the files.

You might read each file and save a record to a database containing elements such as the email address and perhaps other details about that document, and then with that record store a pointer (a path) to the file itself.

That way when you need to perform a search you're executing a SQL query, not scanning billions of files.

I disagree with using a `Dictionary`. Where is that dictionary going to come from? If you're using an index (like a SQL table or tables) then you'll query that. There would be no reason to query the tables and build a gigantic in-memory dictionary. What if you also wanted the files to be queryable by some other attribute. Then what - create another dictionary?

And the great big hole in that - it assumes that there will be one file for each email address. What if two contain the same email address? Then you'd have duplicate keys.

If you wanted that much data stored in memory for some reason (like extremely fast performance) it still doesn't change the solution. Newer versions of SQL Server load data into memory. But it's still on the SQL server which can handle queries much more efficiently.

The question about which collection to use was prefaced with "also", suggesting it's not central to the problem. That's good, because I don't think it's relevant at all. If the query returns references to more than one document you could return the results in an `IEnumerable<T>` - the underlying type (`List<T>`, array, etc.) doesn't matter very much.

Comment: You don't get the job. Where is Dictionary going to come from "Assuming data is already being fetched by existing code]".    THE person name as in singular.  What COLLECTION (db is not a collection).   Key lookup on a Dictionary is about 100 as fast as a round trip to a db even with an index on the table.  Best COMPLEXITY is a term used by collections - not db.  Dictionary is not T - it is Key, Value.  Did you down vote me?

Comment: Duplicate email?  That would make email delivery difficult.

Comment: @Paparazzi - It's correct to point out that there's no way a dictionary is going to hold a billion entries in memory, no collection is going to do that. On another hand why push for an artificial index if the data contains one already that being the email address. And _And the great big hole in that - it assumes that there will be one file for each email address. What if two contain the same email address? Then you'd have duplicate keys._ We just understand the question differently, Scott is answering the interviewer while we are thinking about the example class.

Comment: @pijemcolu The stated question is collection and complexity - they are asking about collections.  "billion of data in a file system"  does not mean billionS of emails.  They parsed a few million out.  "Assuming data is already being fetched by existing code"  fair assumption they fit that in memory.

Comment: @Paparazzi We can only assume what the original question was about. I dont think though it is incorrect to assume that it was an open ended question where one had to argue about both a possible divide and conquer strategy with an in memory collection representation of the data, such as our lovely dictionary which is implemented as a hashset under the hood as well as pointing out that it is simply impossible to query in real time all the data at once. No point in arguing now anyways.

Comment: My answer is biased by the fact that it's an interview question (which perhaps means it doesn't fit the forum anyway.) I can't assume that the interview included this detail: "Let's we have billion of data in a file system" for absolutely no reason. "Data is already being fetched by existing code" - what does that mean? What data? If it's not *all* the data from billions of files then how can you search it for a given email? You'd have to go to the source anyway, so the fact that data is fetched becomes irrelevant.

Comment: As for the duplicate emails - a file system is not a database. It does not have unique constraints other than the file name. (There are not constraints on what is within the files, like email addresses.) It would be a wild assumption that you can accumulate billions of files and the email addresses contained within them won't be duplicated. I wouldn't want to explain that my app had a defect because I made that assumption. How do you know if there are duplicates? Build an index.

Comment: "My task was to find the Person name using the email id as search criteria with best case complexity" is pretty darn clear to me.  The person name is singular.  "Also, what collection is best suited for this?"   I am going to take that as "collection" not database.  A system in place to fetch the data (name, email) is irrelevant?  So you would ignore existing code to fetch data and start from scratch?  Pretty sure you don't get the job.

Comment: I don't get the job. Neither does anyone else who answered the question. The description is inadequate. The only reason I can see asking a question like this in an interview is to see if the developer is smart enough to keep asking questions until they figure out what I really mean. One such question would be, "What do you mean the data from billions of files is already fetched?" Another would be, "Are there any pre-existing unique constraints on the data in the *billions* of files?"

Comment: Cool. Question is adequate for me.